# Does the following code violate Persistence Ignorance rule

Tags: entity-framework, design-patterns, orm, domain-driven-design

a)  *Domain entities* shouldn't contain code related to persistence, thus they should be *Persistence Ignorant* **PI**. But assuming *Domain Model* **DM** is designed using *Entity Framework* and assuming  that *service layer* performs CRUD operation for **POCO** *domain entities*  via *Linq-to-Entities*, would we argue that *service layer* accesses DAL directly or via *Domain Model*:

```
class CustomerService
{
       public string doSomething( ... )
       {
                ...
                var customer = context.Customers.Where( ... );
                ...
        }
       ...
}
```

b) Does using *Linq-to-Entities* within **DM** violate **PI**  rule? For example, does the following `Customer` entity violate PI:

```
class Customer
{
       public string InterestedWhatOtherCustomerOrdered( ... )
       {
                ...
                var orders = context.Orders.Where( ... ); // does this violate PI rule?
                ...
        }
       ...
}
```

**REPLY TO Luke McGregor:**

a)

> Yeah it does as it refers to the context directly. A better way would
>   be to use the internal navigation properties on Customer to perform
>   the same action,

So instead *navigation properties* should contact the *context*?! But since *navigation properties* also reside within domain model, couldn't we then argue that by contacting the *context* directly, they too would violate **PI**?

b) According to *Fowler's PEAA chapter on Data Mapper*, it is ok to extract from *Data Mapper* any methods needed by the domain code into an interface class, which domain code can then use. How exactly could that be done when using **EF** instead of hand written *Data Mapper*, in such a manner that we wouldn't violate **PI**?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah it does as it refers to the context directly. A better way would be to use the internal navigation properties on Customer to perform the same action,

```
class Customer
{
       public string InterestedWhatOtherCustomerOrdered( ... )
       {
                ...
                var orders = this.Orders;
                ...
        }
       ...
}
```

or to create a separate query class for this function.

Comment: @user702769 navigation properties are generally considered part of the model not part of the persistence layer. This is because you could have a similar object structure with nav properties and use a completely different persistence layer. Nav properties arent really contacting the context at all (except with some proxy implementations) they are describing a relationship between two entites in our domain. EF (and other orms) interperate this relationship and turn it into something you can persist to a database

Comment: 1 - I realize nav properties are part of a DM. But to my knowledge they are contacting the context?! 2 - Any ideas with regards to b) question?

Comment: @user702769 in terms of the Data Mapper, im not too sure as I don't have the book in front of me but I imagine this is referring to a query/dao type class which allows our domain to perform queries against the persistence layer. By turning this into an interface we can use the query class without ever needing to directly reference a class which refers to the specific implementation of our persistence layer. This is a way we can de-couple implementation from usage.

Comment: @user702769 In fact DDD is a lot about decoupling components from outside our domains so that we can safely allow higher cohesion within our domains

Comment: @user702769 IE lets remove references where possible to domain external concerns (such as persistence) so we can focus on whats important to us, the data and how it relates to other entities inside our domain

Comment: 1 -"IE lets remove references where possible to domain external concerns(such as persistence)so we can focus on whats important to us" This is confusing - I thought domain code contacting EF wouldn't violate PI,since EF is already decoupled from the concrete DAL implementation ( ie we're able to change the back-end database without having to recompile the application ).Also, if domain code needs some data, but it doesn't know where this data comes from ( as I thought was the case when DM is using Linq-to-entities ), I would considered this as still adhering to DDD?! And focusin

Comment: 2 -  "in terms of the Data Mapper, im not too sure as I don't have the book in front of me but I imagine this is referring to a query/dao type class which allows our domain to perform queries against the persistence layer. " I haven't yet covered query/dao chapter, but it seems he was thinking of extracting the interface from Data Mappers in general and not just from special versions of Data Mappers ( I'm assuming query class is a specialization of a Data Mapper)

Comment: @user702769 my feeling is that EF is part of the persistence layer. While it does allow for a certain level of ignorance around the specific provider of your database its coupled tightly to a database/SQL in general. This means for example if you do not make the separation clear its hard to go to another persistence mechanism such as Memcache or nosql. by making your model unaware of how its persisted you can store the same model in SQL (via ef) or another persisitance layer via another mechanism

Comment: I apologize for taking so much of your time - "my feeling is that EF is part of the persistence layer" A hypothetical question - if EF was somehow completely decoupled from persistence layer (thus we could run EF on top of say Nhibernate), would code from the original post "var orders = context.Orders.Where( ... );" still violate PI?

Comment: @user702769 I dont feel that this would directly violate PI if the context was completely abstracted away from the implementation of the persistence layer. However I still feel that this would be bad practice as it means that your model has to be aware of the context. Ideally a model should only be aware of the data it describes.

Comment: "Ideally a model should only be aware of the data it describes." I understand your point, but model has to get data it is interested in from somewhere. In other words, it has to ask some class C to get that data --> thus it has to be aware of C! Is it really important whether C is actually an EF's context (assuming EF is completely decoupled from persistence layer) or some other class residing in a domain layer?

Comment: @user702769 'but model has to get data it is interested in from somewhere' I disagree here. the model itself doesnt have to be at all aware of the place its created. EF allows us to have poco classes which do not in any way reference EF. This means our model can be completely seperated from EF and what EF does do is to populate our POCO models with data from the database

Comment: I didnt think this discussion would last as long as it did and I am grateful for you having the patience. I will wrap it up

Comment: "...This means our model can be completely seperated from EF and what EF does do is to populate our POCO models with data from the database"  But you're assuming that every data needed by domain model can be provided through navigation properties or by upper layers ( such as service layer ). Aren't there occasions where some domain entity must dynamically decide what data it needs and as such only way to get that data is by performing Linq-to-entities query (again assuming hypothetical situation that EF is completely decoupled from persistence layer)?

Comment: @user702769 I would say that is the decision of the query/dto layer not the model/entity itself

Comment: I assume query/dto layer sits on top of a domain model? Thus instead of query layer we could also say "it is a decision of a service layer" (since service layer also sits on top of a domain model)?

Comment: thank you both for helping me out and apologies for dragging the discussion for so long

Answer (score 2):

a) There are different flavors of services in DDD. A Domain layer service shouldn't reference the Entity Framework context since it would tightly couple the domain with a particular means of persistence -same as Domain entity, see below. By contrast, an Application layer service could use the context (for instance to call `SaveChanges()`) because it knows about the current unit of work and *when* things should be persisted.

b) As Luke said, yes it does violate PI since the Entity Framework context is persistence-specific. In your entity, you should use a persistence-agnostic way of getting the Orders you want.

I don't quite get what your `InterestedWhatOtherCustomerOrdered()` method does (why return a string ? ...) but you could have :

```
class Customer
{
       public string InterestedWhatOtherCustomerOrdered( ... )
       {
                ...
                var orders = OrderRepository.GetOtherCustomerOrdersByInterest(...);
                ...
        }
       ...
}
```

provided that `Orders` is an Aggregate Root. If it isn't, you could use a Domain layer service that turns to an Infrastructure layer service for the querying or directly ask the Orders from their own Aggregate Root(s).

Comment: Shouldn't Application layer services also adhere to PI rule? If yes, then won't Application layer service using EF context violate the PI rule ( due to EF being persistence specific )?

Comment: When we talk about PI we generally mean PI of domain layer objects, not application layer objects. It's not uncommon to see application layers with a reference to the persistence layer. But you're right, ideally the application layer should shield itself from the specifics of one ORM framework or another. Defining your own IUnitOfWork can help you to do so.

Comment: Any idea why ( compared to domain layer objects ) it is less important  for application layer services to adhere to PI?

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's because the domain is seen as a "purer" entity that is more important to keep clear of unwanted persistence details. The application layer being a lower layer than the domain, it is also less likely to be reused in another architecture so in most cases you can afford to couple your app services tightly with other layers (except of course the UI).

Comment: "a lower layer than the domain" Since application layer sits on top of domain layer, I assume that by "lower layer" you're referring to its lower importance (as far as a reusability goes) compared to domain layer?

Comment: Depends on what you put at the top and bottom ;) If dependencies go upwards, domain is the topmost layer. From an Onion Architecture perspective, with dependencies going from the outside in, it's the centermost layer.